# Uso dialettale di articoli senza L

Tags: regional, articles

(Avvertimento: leggo l'italiano, ma non lo so scrivere bene.)

Da tempo ho notato che in tutta l'area che per me è a primo sguardo linguisticamente 'macro-italiana' (Firenze fino a Palermo, tutti hanno consonanti doppie e preservano le occlusive intervocaliche latine), le forme dialettali dell'articolo determinativo lasciano spesso cadere la L: ecco `a` e `o/u` invece di `la` e `il`. Pare normale in napoletano, ma l'ho trovato anche in corso e siciliano.

- È una caratteristica dell'italiano popolare che non riuscì a essere adottata dalla lingua 'corretta'? Ci sono dialetti dove non accade, mai?
- Ci sono delle regole per la perdita della L o dipende del registro?

(L'articolo è `a`/`o` in portoghese - da qui la mia curiosità - e aragonese; in entrambe le lingue, è uno sviluppo secondario; il portoghese perse regolarmente la -L- ma non la -LL-.)

Comment: Per il romanesco (il dialetto/italiano regionale parlato a Roma), questo è un esempio dell'effetto della “lex Porena”, la scomparsa della laterale (la “l”) in certe parole (articoli, preposizioni articolate, pronomi) derivati dal latino *ille*; per esempio, *a robba*, ma anche *joo ddetto* (corrispondente a “gliel'ho detto”) etc. La cosa interessante è che è un fenomeno recente, storicamente. C' è qualcosa in merito [qui](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/speciali/italiano_dialetti/D_Achille.html) e altrove (cerca appunto “lex Porena”). Per le altre parti d'Italia, non so.

Comment: Nei dialetti settentrionali la “l” rimane; in veneto il suono è diverso, ma è solo una questione di pronuncia.

Comment: Anche in milanese la "l" rimane: *la cadrega*, *el taul*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doverosa premessa, i dialetti italiani sono così tanti e variegati ed inoltre in molti casi non seguono delle regole ben definite, quindi è difficile rispondere a questa domanda.

Ci provo, partendo dal dialetto parlato nella mia città, Taranto, di conseguenza del dialetto tarantino.

Secondo [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetto_tarantino) (ed io concordo)

gli articoli determinativi sono i seguenti:

- 'u (corrisponde nella lingua italiana a **il / lo**) - singolare maschile
- 'a (corrisponde nella lingua italiana a **la**) - singolare femminile
- le (corrisponde nella lingua italiana a **i / gli / le**) - plurale

Andando oltre Wikipedia, il "Dizionario della parlata tarantina" di Nicola Gigante (Mandese Editore) sull'articolo 'u dice quando segue:

> art. determ. m., il, usato dinanzi a consonante: 'u cielə (il cielo),
>   'u petə (il piede), 'u zianə (lo zio); e davanti a nomi che cominciano
>   per vocale per la perdita della consonante iniziale: 'u uagnonə (il
>   ragazzo), 'u uandə (il guanto). Per Meyer Lubke è una forma
>   raccorciata; per Rohlfs è variazione atona del pronome; secondo il
>   Merlo è il risultato di una pronunzia velare di: lo > 'u; mentre il
>   mantenersi del lə dinanzi a vocale velare non può se non essere una
>   dissimilazione.

Se però, ci spostiamo a Lecce (circa 90 km da Taranto), beh li è il regno del *lu* (articolo determinativo maschile singolare).

Il leccese rientra nella categoria dei dialetti meridionali estremi (assimilabile al siciliano), dove l'uso degli articoli determinativi è promiscuo, [qui trovi la pagina di Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_siciliana#Articoli)

Spero di esserti stato d'aiuto.

Answer (score -3):

Da quello che so è principalmente una caratteristica dei dialetti dal centro Italia in giù (Lazio fino alla Sicilia) dove i termini usati sono derivati molto più direttamente dal greco antico e dal latino.
I dialetti del nord hanno invece influenze più nord europee, francesi, svizzere e tedesche principalmente.

Non ci sono regole specifiche. La *L* è rimossa nell'articolo. O meglio non esiste.

Comment: Poi vorrei spiegato il perché del voto negativo.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!  Il voto negativo non è mio, ma forse il problema è l'assenza di fonti e la spiegazione un po' superficiale.

Comment: Formuli varie affermazioni, nessuna delle quali fornita di giustificazioni, citazioni o esempi e che, personalmente, considero poco attendibili.

Comment: @DaG OK... Quindi sei in disaccordo con la mia risposta? La reputi sbagliata?

Comment: @Tony, da quello che sai? Fammi capire il tuo sapere, ha un libro di riferimento? Sono voci di corridoio? O lo sai da conversazioni popolane/dialettali dal centro Italia in giù e su? Se è per quest'ultimo, io vivo nel sud Italia e quel 'principalmente", nella tua risposta, non è tanto corretto e vorrei capire di più, magari con qualche fonte almeno attendibile di come "principalmente" il tedesco & company influenzano o hanno influenzato i dialetti del Nord.

Comment: @mle il mio sapere deriva principalmente dal fatto che ho vissuto sia al nord che al sud e ho imparato i dialetti delle diverse città in cui ho risieduto. Cercando su Google puoi trovare decine di articoli pubblicati da diverse università e istituti di ricerca che trattano delle influenze europee sulla lingua italiana e i dialetti. Ne Allego uno per riferimento. http://www.homolaicus.com/letteratura/questione_lingua.htm

Comment: @TonyMorello: Non trovo dove si parla degli articoli determinativi nel testo che citi...